# Initial cursor placement in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: datagridview

This is the first time I am using a datagrid view (am also a bit of a VB.NET
novice).  The issue I am having is that when the form displays, the blinking
cursor does not display in the cell until I actually click in the cell or start
keying data, nor does it display when I tab to the next cell until I actually
click in the cell or start keying data.  The following is the code I have in
the LOAD event for the form.

```
dgv.Rows.Add()
dgv.ClearSelection()
dgv.CurrentCell = dgvRows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(2)
dgvBscvrgGrpCd.Select()
```

It was recommended earlier that I add the statement dgv.BeginEdit(True).
The code now looks as follows:

```
dgv.Rows.Add()
dgv.ClearSelection()
dgv.CurrentCell = dgvRows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(2)
dgvBscvrgGrpCd.Select()
dgv.BeginEdit(True)
```

The blinking cursor still does not appear in the cell until I actually click in
the cell and I can no longer just start keying data.  I have a click in the cell
to be able to enter data.  The column is defined as READONLY = FALSE.  What am I missing?  Do I need an additional code or is the code in the wrong event?  Any
help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the blinking cursor indicates the grid is in edit mode.  There is EDITMODE a property for the grid.  The default value is EditOnKeyStrokeOrF2.  I changed this value to EditOnEnter and the blinking cursor now appears.